# DjangoRestFramework - View is able to create a user object without any input for mandatory fields

Tags: django, validation, http-post, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4.0. I am using the DjangoRestFramework. I want to create a User object. According to

```
django/contrib/auth/models.py
```

it says

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this model.
    Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
```

Now in my serializers.py file, I have:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

and in my views.py file, I have:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list(request):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In my urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^users$', 'user_list', name='user_list'),
```

I ran the server and then opened up the terminal and did

```
curl -X POST localhost:8000/users/ -d "username=firstUser&password=firstPassword"
```

it returned a 201 created status code and the object was successfully created. Since the "class User" mentioned that the email field is mandatory, shouldn't it have returned a 400 bad request status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the "class User" mentioned that the email field is mandatory

*What email field?*

You only told Django REST framework that there is a `username` and `password` field, so that is all it expects and validates. If you want the `email` field to be required, you are going to have to include it in `Meta.fields` on your serializer.

*Side note: [`email` isn't actually a required field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3cb386b8c2b2d7d72a3778c89d5d1f997fa0cad8/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L399).*

Comment: oh, you're right, it isn't a required field. Any idea why in the link you had and in "class User(AbstractUser)" - which is located in the file django/contrib/auth/models.py - it mentions that "Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional."? Is that a typo in Django? Note: on line 411 in the document you linked, it says "REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']" but I looked through the rest of the file and it doesn't do anything with the "REQUIRED_FIELDS" variable.

Comment: @user2719875 It's "required" if you want to use in the built-in email functionality, but otherwise it looks like it might be a typo.

Comment: interesting. Okay so what I tried now was that in my serializers.py, I made "fields = ('username', )" for testing purposes. I then tried to create a user object by doing 'curl -X POST localhost:8000/users/ -d "username=firstUser"' and it successfully created the user object (even though in models.py "class User" it says that the password field is required). Is this the correct behavior? I thought that Django wouldn't allow me to create an object if the original model has a mandatory field which isn't being inputted when instantiating the object. Doesn't the database not allow a blank password?

Comment: @user2719875 The password can be unset by default, that's intentional. Keep in mind that all of these are required arguments to `User.objects.create_user()`.

Comment: right, I was under the impression that when I do "serializer.is_valid()", since the serializer is linked to the User Model, then it would have to meet the User Model's requirements (i.e a password is required) but I guess not. Is there any way for to make "serializer.is_valid()" for the UserSerializer verify that it is meeting the User Model's requirements (i.e verifying that a valid username and password is provided)?